# Issue using pgr_dijkstra from Postgres pgRouting

Tags: postgis, postgresql, pgrouting

I am using Postgres with Postgis extension to retrieve streets (only for pedestrian use) and several "natural" points. I need to make updates every minute and i am working on a small bounding box.
For rendering I am using leaflet that makes request to a java servlet and all is working well...Postgres is populated with "osm2pgsql".

I would implement some kind of routing service, unfortunately i am not expert with PLPGSQL dialect  but i found this excellent post in [LOUDHUSH BLOG](http://blog.loudhush.ro/2011/10/using-pgrouting-on-osm-database.html?showComment=1326783736224#c8406204422839973852).
To make it work I had to change the name of the last function to "pgr_createTopology":

```
drop table if exists network;
create table network(gid serial, osm_id bigint, name varchar, the_geom     
geometry, source bigint, target bigint, length float);


CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION compute_network() RETURNS text as $$
DECLARE
streetRecord record;
wayRecord record;
pointCount integer;
pointIndex integer;
geomFragment record;
BEGIN

-- for each street
FOR streetRecord in select way, osm_id, name from planet_osm_line where     
highway is not null LOOP

-- for each street in the region of interest
 SELECT * from planet_osm_ways where id = streetRecord.osm_id into wayRecord; 
 FOR pointIndex in array_lower(wayRecord.nodes, 1)..array_upper(wayRecord.nodes,1)-1 LOOP

RAISE NOTICE 'Inserting name % source %, target %', streetRecord.name, wayRecord.nodes[pointIndex], wayRecord.nodes[pointIndex+1];
  select st_makeline(st_pointn(streetRecord.way, pointIndex), st_pointn(streetRecord.way, pointIndex+1)) as way into geomFragment;
  insert into network(osm_id, name, the_geom, source, target, length) values(streetRecord.osm_id, streetRecord.name, geomFragment.way,
  wayRecord.nodes[pointIndex], wayRecord.nodes[pointIndex+1], st_length(geomFragment.way));
 END LOOP;
END LOOP;
return 'Done';
END;
$$ LANGUAGE 'plpgsql';

select * from compute_network();
select pgr_createTopology('network', 1, 'the_geom', 'gid');
```

"network" table is populated in the right manner..i think,
before to run Shortest Path Dijkstra i changed manually "source" and "target" column to integer type but the query below return an empty table

```
CREATE TABLE route AS SELECT seq, id1 AS node, id2 AS edge, cost, b.the_geom FROM pgr_dijkstra('
            SELECT gid AS id,
                     source::integer,
                     target::integer,
                     length::double precision AS cost
                    FROM network',
            41, 50, false, false) a LEFT JOIN ways b ON (a.id2 = b.gid);
```

can you tell me what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

The source and target parameters in pgr_dijkstra are id's of vertices, not edges. I assume 41 and 50 are edge id's = column gid in table network.

Moreover pgrouting is constrained to 32bit-integers as edge- and vertex-id's, so you can't use OSM-id's directly, as they are too big.

Comment: In pgRouting 2.1.0 this limit is lifted so pg_dijikstra works with bigints as well.

Comment: wow, i'll try it, working only with integers is a bit frustrating, thanks Redoute for reply but the problem is solved keeping empty "source" and "target" columns and than running "pgr_createTopology"